# Rails filtering with ajax and render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to make filtering function with ajax and render partial. The reason why I need these two is because there is an element I should not reload. Because of this I'm trying to get a filtered data by ajax and render partial the filtered data. If there is anything I should let you know more, please tell me.

Making index page work is fine.

controllers/item_controller.rb

```
def index
    @items = Item.all
end
```

views/item/index.html.erb

```
<div>
    An element that should not be reloaded
</div>
<div id="item_list_wrapper">
    <%= render partial: 'item/item_list' %>
</div>
```

views/item/item_list.erb

```
<% @items.each do |i| %>
    something
<% end %>
```

When I click a button, ajax is called and item/item_list.erb is reloaded.

controllers/item_controller.rb

```
def item_filter
    filtered_items = Item.where(filtered item)
    render json: filtered_items
end
```

javascript

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/item/filter',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      price: $('#price').val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#item_list_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item/item_list') %>");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

I can see the ajax called data in my console. It took me several days but I  really cannot find out a way to use the ajax called data as @items in the reloaded item/item_list.erb. Thanks in advance for all comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The ERB interpolation (anything in ERB tags `<% %>` or `<%= %>`) happens on the server before the the javascript is sent to the client. If your script is placed in `app/assets/javascripts` this done when the scripts are compiled at deploy time.

The Ajax request happens later on the client.

You either need to do the templating on the client side:

```
var $template = $('<li></li>');
var promise = $.getJSON(
  url: '/item/filter',
  data: {
      price: $('#price').val()
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
      $("#item_list_wrapper").append( $template.clone().text(value));
    };
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('error');
  }
)
```

Or use a `js.erb` template:

```
var promise = $.ajax(
  url: '/item/filter',
  data: {
      price: $('#price').val()
  },
  dataType: 'application/javascript',
  error: function(){
    alert('error');
  }
)
```

You can also use Rails UJS to send the ajax request by adding the `data-remote="true"` to the form (usually done by adding `remote: true` to the form helper options).

```
# defaults to the js format
# set "data-type" => :json to send JSON instead
<%= form_tag('/item/filter', remote: true) %>
  <%= number_field_tag(:price) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter items' %>
<% end %>
```

You need to setup your controller to respond to the `js` format:

```
class ItemsController
  def filter
    # ...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
// app/items/views/filter.js.erb
$("#item_list_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item/item_list') %>");
```

Comment: Also your route should be named `/items` in plural.

Comment: I believe the file name should be app/views/items/filter.js.erb

Comment: Good catch @abax.

Comment: Of the two I think sticking with JSON is better. `js.erb` tends to turn into this mess where your start adding all these crazy non-restful routes just to update the client instead of building a decent REST api. It also makes the JS very fragmented and hard to DRY or even maintain properly.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on your comment? Are you saying that if you had multiple similar features they could reuse the first answer you provided? Would that be by changing it to a function which would take the url, form, and destination #id? @max

Comment: If your controller returns good JSON responses you can consume it in any number of ways in the client without adding complexity to the rails application. You can also later change it over to a full SPA such as Ember, React, Vue.js etc. @abax

Comment: The promise of `js.erb` is that it lets you use Rails templating system, however architecture wise its a horrible solution - especially for noobs that a already struggling to understand how ajax works and what happens in the client and what happens on the server. You get going quick but it also gets messy really quick. @abax

Comment: @max Thank a lot both of you for quick and perfect answers!! I should have thought the compile timing you pointed out earlier!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have to do with not passing in the `data` to your partial. Try changing views/item/item_list.erb to

`<% items.each do |i| %>
    something
<% end %>`

then call it in your view:

`<%= render partial: 'item/item_list', locals: { items: @items } %>`

then finally pass in data to the partial using JS:

`$("#item_list_wrapper").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'item/item_list', locals: { items: data }) %>");`

Having said all that, I'd also recommend learning to use remote => true to simplify your js. I've found this guide straightforward: https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy

Comment: Thank a lot both of you for quick and perfect answers!! I should have thought the compile timing earlier!!